# Doctrine 2, HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD wont fetch joined entities

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

there is a voucher:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="VoucherCode", mappedBy="voucher")
 */
protected $voucherCode;
```

and voucher code:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Entity\Voucher
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Doctrine\Entity\Voucher", inversedBy="voucherCode")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="voucher_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $voucher;
```

if I do a query builder on voucherCode and add a `$qb->leftJoin('x.voucher', 'v');` then it wont query the vouchers, `->getVoucher()` is NULL... although viewing the DQL, leftjoin do takes place.

If I remove the `->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true));` then it works OK. Whats the matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html?highlight=HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD#query-hints) is not crystal clear (at least to me) on how related objects are loaded with that query hint set, like in your situation:

> Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD - Allows to hydrate objects although not all their columns are fetched. This query hint can be used to handle memory consumption problems with large result-sets that contain char or binary data. Doctrine has no way of implicitly reloading this data. Partially loaded objects have to be passed to EntityManager::refresh() if they are to be reloaded fully from the database.

My guess is that you can keep the hint on, but then your DQL must include the partial code for the voucher (`SELECT partial x.{voucher_id, name}...`).

If your largest related objects are always loaded with your own DQL, you can remove this query hint and always load with your own partial queries.  Usually I prefer to optimize memory consumption and performance with custom repositories and DQL.

Comment: thanks, but it turned out I need to query the joined table too. So: not just ->select() BUT ->select('v'); But I marked you as "accepted" since you were the one who dealed with me :)